# Awk replace nth Character with blank value

Tags: awk

I have the below file with 100s of entries which I want to replace the 46th Character (N) with a blank with an awk command on a unix box. Does anyone know the best way to do this?

```
TESTENTRY1||||||N|Y|N|OFF||N||||N|L|N|0|N|0|N|N||||A|0||0||N|N|N|Y|N||0|N|N||0|||N|N|N|N|N
TESTENTRY2||||||N|Y|N|OFF||N||||N|L|N|0|N|0|N|N||||A|0||0||N|N|N|Y|N||0|N|N||0|||N|N|N|N|N
```

So it looks like the below:

```
TESTENTRY1||||||N|Y|N|OFF||N||||N|L|N|0|N|0|N|N||||A|0||0||N|N|N|Y|N||0|N|N||0|||N||N|N|N
TESTENTRY2||||||N|Y|N|OFF||N||||N|L|N|0|N|0|N|N||||A|0||0||N|N|N|Y|N||0|N|N||0|||N||N|N|N
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" } { $46 = "" }1' nnn.txt
TESTENTRY1||||||N|Y|N|OFF||N||||N|L|N|0|N|0|N|N||||A|0||0||N|N|N|Y|N||0|N|N||0|||N||N|N|N
TESTENTRY2||||||N|Y|N|OFF||N||||N|L|N|0|N|0|N|N||||A|0||0||N|N|N|Y|N||0|N|N||0|||N||N|N|N
```

> `BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" }` sets the input and output field separators to the vertical bar before the records are read.
>
> `{ $46 = "" }` sets the 46th column to be empty in each record.
>
> The trailing `1` prints the resulting record to the output.